# Searching a queue in C

Tags: c, queue

Let's say I have this structure:

```
struct Runway0Landing{

    char fdetails[10];
    int ArrivalTimeHours;
    int ArrivalTimeMins;
    int MinsToLand;
    int MinsForFuel;
    int passengers;
    int WaitingTime;
    struct Runway0Landing *nextPtr;

};

typedef struct Runway0Landing RunZeroLand;
typedef RunZeroLand *RunZeroLandPtr;
```

And this function to add values to the queue;

```
void AddToRunway0L(RunZeroLandPtr *r0LhPtr,RunZeroLandPtr *r0LtPtr,char fdetails[],int ArrivalTimeHours,int ArrivalTimeMins,int MinsForFuel,int passengers)
{
    RunZeroLandPtr newPtr;
    int WaitingTime=0;

    newPtr=malloc(sizeof(RunZeroLand));

    if( newPtr!=NULL)
    {
        strncpy(newPtr->fdetails,fdetails,sizeof(RunZeroLand));
        newPtr->ArrivalTimeHours=ArrivalTimeHours;
        newPtr->ArrivalTimeMins=ArrivalTimeMins;
        newPtr->MinsForFuel=MinsForFuel;
        newPtr->passengers=passengers;
        newPtr->WaitingTime=0;
        newPtr->nextPtr=NULL;


        if( isEmptyL0(*r0LhPtr))
        {
            *r0LhPtr=newPtr;
        }

        else
        {
            (*r0LtPtr)->nextPtr=newPtr;
        }

            *r0LtPtr=newPtr;
        }




}
```

I have tried this approach but the program just crashes:

```
void RemoveFromQueue(RunZeroLandPtr *r0LhPtr,int MinsForFuel)
{
    r0LhPtr previousPtr;
    r0LhPtr currentPtr;
    r0LhPtr tempPtr;

    char plane[10];
    int passengers;
    int ArrivalTimeHours;
    int ArrivalTimeMins;
    int MinsForFuel;

    strcpy(plane,(*r0LhPtr)->fdetails);

    passengers=(*r0LhPtr)->passengers;
    ArrivalTimeHours=(*r0LhPtr)->ArrivalTimeHours;
    ArrivalTimeMins=(*r0LhPtr)->ArrivalTimeMins;






    if(MinsForFuel == (*r0LhPtr)->MinsForFuel)
    {
        tempPtr=*r0LhPtr;
        *r0LhPtr=(*r0LhPtr)->nextPtr;
        free(tempPtr);





    }
    else
    {
        previousPtr=*r0LhPtr;
        currentPtr=(*r0LhPtr)->nextPtr;

        while(currentPtr!=NULL && currentPtr->MinsForFuel != MinsForFuel)
        {
            previousPtr=currentPtr;
            currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;

        }

        if(currentPtr!=NULL)
        {
            tempPtr=currentPtr;
            previousPtr->nextPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
            free(tempPtr);



    }




}
```

I need a function that would check all the nodes in the queue for a particular criterion ( i.e: checks if `MinsForFuel` is equal to 0 ) and removes it from the queue.I have initialised r0LhPtr and r0LtPtr ( head and tail pointers for the queue ) as NULL in the main.
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Is there a specific part of building such a function you don't understand?

Comment: I tried a method using previous,current and temp pointers that I have used on a linked list but it wouldn't work and would crash instead. My linked list only had a head pointer but this queue has a head and a tail and am not really sure how to go about it.

Comment: I believe you should edit your question to add those details (and perhaps some examples) instead of adding them as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should adapt your function `AddToRunway0L`:

```
    if( isEmptyL0(*r0LhPtr) )
    {
        // list is empty => head and tail point to the same and only element
        *r0LhPtr = *r0LtPtr = newPtr;
    }

    else
    {
        // append new element at tail, new element is new tail
        (*r0LtPtr)->nextPtr = newPtr;
        *r0LtPtr = newPtr;
    }
```

If you remove an element from your list you have to test first if the head element is the element you want to remove. If not you have to iterate until the next element is the element to be removed.

```
void RemoveFromQueue(RunZeroLandPtr *r0LhPtr, RunZeroLandPtr *r0LtPtr, int MinsForFuel)
{
    RunZeroLandPtr tempPtr;
    RunZeroLandPtr currentPtr;

    if ( isEmptyL0(*r0LhPtr) )
        return;

    if (MinsForFuel == (*r0LhPtr)->MinsForFuel)
    {
        // head element will be removed
        tempPtr = *r0LhPtr;
        *r0LhPtr = (*r0LhPtr)->nextPtr;
        if ( *r0LtPtr == tempPtr ) //  there was only one element
            *r0LtPtr = *r0LhPtr;
        free( tempPtr );
        return;  
    }    

    currentPtr = *r0LhPtr;  
    while ( currentPtr->nextPtr != NULL && MinsForFuel != currentPtr->nextPtr->MinsForFuel )
    {
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    if ( currentPtr->nextPtr != NULL )
    {
        //  the next element is the element you want to remove
        tempPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        currentPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr->nextPtr ;
        if ( *r0LtPtr == tempPtr ) //  the removed elemtent is tail
            *r0LtPtr = currentPtr;
        free( tempPtr );
    }
    return;
}
```